# Tail-recursive pow() algorithm with memoization?

Tags: algorithm, tail-recursion, memoization, exponentiation

I'm looking for an algorithm to compute `pow()` that's tail-recursive and uses memoization to speed up repeated calculations.

Performance isn't an issue; this is mostly an intellectual exercise - I spent a train ride coming up with all the different `pow()` implementations I could, but was unable to come up with one that I was happy with that had these two properties.

My best shot was the following:

```
def calc_tailrec_mem(base, exp, cache_line={}, acc=1, ctr=0):
    if exp == 0:
        return 1
    elif exp == 1:
        return acc * base
    elif exp in cache_line:
        val = acc * cache_line[exp]
        cache_line[exp + ctr] = val
        return val
    else:
        cache_line[ctr] = acc        
    return calc_tailrec_mem(base, exp-1, cache_line, acc * base, ctr + 1)
```

It works, but it doesn't memoize the results of all calculations - only those with exponents `1..exp/2` and `exp`.

Comment: It's memoization, not memorization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: Wow, that's a scary use of Python's default arguments. You're actually emulating a global variable there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're recording the correct thing in your cache, the mapping changed when you call it with different arguments.

I think you need to have a cache of (base,exp) -> pow(base,exp).

I understand what `ctr` is for, and why only half of what you expect is recorded.

Consider `calc_tailrec_mem(2,4)`: First level, pow(2,1) is recorded as 2, the next level = `calc_tailrec_mem(2,3,...)`, and pow(2,2) is recorded. The next level is `calc_tailrec_mem(2,2,...)`, but that is already saved in the cache, so the recursion stops.

The function is very confusing because it's caching something completely different from what it's supposed to be calculating, due to the acculumator and `ctr`.

Comment: You're right about the first two points; the recording in the code is exp -> pow(base,exp) - there's some code elsewhere that keeps track of the base and makes sure that the calculations are recorded in the right place.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get better performance if you use the successive squaring technique described in [SICP section 1.2.4 Exponentiation](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.4).  It doesn't use memoization, but the general approach is O(log n) instead of O(n), so you should still see an improvement.

I talk about the solution to the iterative process from exercise 1.16 [here](https://billthelizard.blogspot.com/2010/01/sicp-exercise-116-fast-exponentiation.html).

Comment: I'm not in the market for performance (or to use this in anything real) - this was a somewhat arbitrary challenge I set myself that I can't figure out the answer to.

Answer (score 0):

This is way too late, but anyone out there looking for the answer, here it is:

```cpp
int powMem(int base,int exp){
    //initializes once and for all
    static map<int,int> memo;

    //base case to stop the recursion
    if(exp <= 1) return base;

    //check if the value is already calculated before. If yes just return it.
    if(memo.find(exp) != memo.end())
        return memo[exp];

    //else just find it and then store it in memo for further use.
    int x = powMem(base,exp/2);
    memo[exp] = x*x;

    //return the answer
    return memo[exp];
}
```

This uses the memo array - a map , to be exact - to store the already calculated values.